# incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIImageView*' from 'UIImage*'

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, incompatibletypeerror

Hi I am getting this error on my code,  I have no clue how to fix it . [image]

Suggestions and answers would be awesome. Thanks :D

Comment: This question is kind of linked to the previous question. So you can get the background story in my previous question. I implemented a suggestion by a user in the previous question and got this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very much understood from the error that you are pointing `UIImage` to `UIImageview` that is not compatible. So You need to use the property `image` of `UIImageview` as follows:

```
[editViewController.chosenImage setImage:self.Image];
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax would be:

```
editViewController.chosenImage.image = self.Image
```

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers are correct but it's worth explaining that UIImage is just an object. It is a direct subclass of NSObject. UIImageView is a view (subclass of UIView) that takes a UIImage as one of its properties and displays it.